# Python with excel - Find duplicate rows, append corresponding columns and append some values to new column

Tags: python, excel

Using python and an excel sheet: If I have column1 with a row of numbers and every three to four rows for column1 are duplicate. Column2 has each row with different values and value* is a key word followed by any random text (represented by a wild card for this example). Column3 is empty.

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | value1, value* |  |
| 1234 | value2, value* |  |
| 1234 | value3 |  |
| 2222 | value4, value* |  |
| 2222 | value5 |  |

1. using python how do I merge duplicates in column1 to show appended values in one row from column2
   For example

   1234 - value1, value2, value3, value*

   2222 - value4, value5, value*
2. Then how do I use a wild card key word to take value3 and everything after and append to column 3 for that duplicate row.

   ```
   1234 - |value1, value2| | value3* |
   2222 - |value4, value5| | value3*|
   ```

Looking for a library with built in functions that may do this with less lines of code. If you have a way to solve this without libraries please feel free to post your solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by not using libraries, but I assume you are able to use the CSV library that comes with Python to read/write the files.

Taking the first part only, and assuming that the order of "valueN" in a column **does not** matter, I would:

1. Read the file using the CSV library's [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to have access to the column names:

```
all_cell_1s = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row['Column1']
    values = row['Column2'].split(",")
    # You may need additional cleaning of whitespace etc. for the items:
    values = [v.strip() for v in values]
    # Get or create a new set() for the key.
    cell_1 = all_cell_1s.setdefault(key, set())
    cell_1.update(values)
```

2. At this point, each entry in `all_cell_1s` contains the de-duplicated
   content from Column1.

If the order **does** matter, then instead of using a `set()` use a `dict()` like this:

```
   # The value of `1` is arbitrary, we are only using a dict because it preserves order of keys.
   values = {v.strip(): 1 for v in values}
   cell_1 = all_cell_1s.setdefault(key, dict())
   cell_1.update(values)
```

and now the keys of each entry in `all_cell_1s` is the de-duplicated content of Column1.

I'm not sure I understand your second question.